# Putting an $A \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}$-module structure on $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V')$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Observe that given an algebra $A$, we can put a $A \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}$ structure on $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V')$ by $$((a \otimes a')f)(v)=af(a'v)$$

Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
   {}& ((a \otimes a')(b \otimes b'))f(v) \\
  ={}& (ab \otimes b'a'))f(v) \\
  ={}& ab(f(b'a'v)) \\
  ={}& a((b \otimes b')f(a'v)) \\
  ={}& (a \otimes a')((b \otimes b')f(v))
\end{align*}

I'm just a bit confused why we need the $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ rather than just $A$... Can we put an $A \otimes A$ structure on $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V')$ by the same formula?

\begin{align*}
   {}& ((a \otimes a')(b \otimes b'))f(v) \\
  ={}& (ab \otimes a'b'))f(v) \\
  ={}& ab(f(a'b'v)) \\
  ={}& (a \otimes a')bf(b'v)) \\
  ={}& (a \otimes a')((b \otimes b')f(v))
\end{align*}

Maybe they both work... Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $(af)(v) = f(av)$ does not define an $A$-action, because it breaks associativity.

$((ab)f)(v)$ should equal $f(abv)$, but

$(a(bf))(v) = (bf)(av) = f(bav)$, reversing the multiplication of $a$ and $b$. This is why this is an $A^{op}$-structure.